# datepicker and dynamic table not using jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read many threads here about my problem, but I haven't found a solution, may be because I'm not the king of JQuery ...

This is very a simple example :

[example](http://dianamahe.free.fr/test_tableaucalendrier2en.php)

When I try to add a new line, datepicker doesn't work. I don't know what to do. 
I use this function to add a new line in my table. (In reality, I have a html page with many table and for each of them i use datepicker)

```
    var champ_date_arrivee = document.createElement('input');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('type','text');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('size','10');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('name','date_t');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('value','');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('id','date_t');
champ_date_arrivee.className='champ_date_input_tableau';
newCell1.appendChild(champ_date_arrivee);
```

and this code for the datepicker :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
 $('.champ_date_input_tableau').datepicker({ /* action sur class date */

    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "c-70:c+70",
    clickInput:true,
 });

});
```

As you can see, I use the class name champ_date_input_tableau, because I don't know how to do it in an other way.

I've tried this :

```
    var champ_date_arrivee = document.createElement('input');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('type','text');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('size','10');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('name','date_t');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('value','');
champ_date_arrivee.setAttribute('id','date_t');
champ_date_arrivee.className='champ_date_input_tableau';
    $(champ_date_arrivee).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "c-70:c+70",
});
newCell1.appendChild(champ_date_arrivee);
```

You have the result on this link [this try](http://dianamahe.free.fr/test_tableaucalendrier4.php)
It doesn't work.

I know that I have to use a code like this, but  how ?

```
 jQuery('.date-pick').removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy'
});
```

You are my last chance ...

Sorry for my english, I'm french.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `.on()`, `.delegate()` or `.live()`. Datepicker is smart enough if you just add it to the bottom of your `ajoutLigneAuTableauTransfert()` function. Because you are modifying the ID attribute after you apply datepicker it is messing up. Specifically call the datepicker plugin after you execute `majNumLignesTabTransfert('ajout');`

(1) Remove the two double up calls you have in `ajoutLigneAuTableauTransfert()`. (2) I also notice you add commas to the end of the last config options which will fail in IE and technically is syntax error in javascript. (3) Add the datepicker call after `majNumLignesTabTransfert('ajout');`

Here's the changes I describe showing it working. Look for `// ANT-MOD` in the javascript comments for indicators.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfDNu/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You take your time, as Dorian Gray and JasCav to help me. Your answer and the quality of you answer is perfect. You help me so much.When I saw the solution, it was so easy in fact. But without you, I will still spend bad nights.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to use jQuery's [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method so

```
$('.champ_date_input_tableau').live('focusin', function() {
    $(this).datepicker();
});​
```

Now go ahead and add more elements, `live` will bind this to new elements too.

**EDIT:**

It is said that `live` is deprecated but there is something works similar I believe called `on`. So please go ahead and use that one if you're really meticulous about using the latest versions all the time

Comment: Check my answer. Not a good idea to use live anymore. It has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because, when your page loads, the date-picker is only hooked up to the already existing form items, but will not be applied to new items. When you add a new row, you need to make sure to call the .datepicker() function on that specific item that has just been added.

Per Dorian's answer you can do this dynamically, but, [DO NOT USE LIVE](http://bitovi.com/blog/2011/04/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live.html). (Read the article for explanations of various issues with it. It has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.) Instead, you need to look into the on() function. Something like this should work:

```
$('#BlocFormulaire').on('click', '.champ_date_input_tableau', function() {
   $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: You could have modified my answer instead of just changing `live` to `on`.

Comment: @DorianGray - True, although I'm unsure of whether or not it is best to use a dynamic event in this situation as I am unfamiliar with the implications of attaching the datepicker every single time (since it is now attached as an event). I still prefer my first answer (which I posted before your answer - I only updated to address your specific response) in that he should make sure to wire up the datepicker as part of dynamically adding the new row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, You keep me alive !

Comment: @Tavarlindar - Happy to help! BTW, if you like answers, a great way to let people know is to up vote the answer. If the answer solved your problem, accept it by selecting the checkmark next to the answer. It lets other people know that you got your solution and it awards reputation to the person who helped you.